# How to use vlfeat sift matching function in C code?

Tags: c, sift, vlfeat

I just found one similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661051/how-does-vl-ubcmatch-work-technically). But I just want to do a matching based on the description result from `vlfeat`. The goal to detect if an image contains the object in another image, based on sift feature description extracting and matching. And I need to do it in C, not Matlab.

So how can I call `vl_ubcmatch` function in C code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how can I call `vl_ubcmatch` function in C code?

This is a [MEX function](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/gateway-routine.html#bt37g83-2) which is *only* intented to be called from MATLAB. You cannot re-use it as-is from a general purpose C program.

> The goal to detect if an image contains the object in another image [...] How to do SIFT matching algorithm if I use vlfeat?

VLFeat C API does not provide SIFT matching functions out-of-the box. So basically you need to adapt the so-called *ratio test* [1] code section from this [MATLAB C code section](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/blob/350c4f0/toolbox/sift/vl_ubcmatch.c#L50-L102) which is fairly easy (see below).

The main drawback if you want to perform robust matching is that this function **does not take into account the geometry**, i.e the keypoints coordinates.

What you need in addition is a geometrical consistency check which is typically performed by figuring out if there is an homography between the two images (using as input the descriptor correspondences obtained with the ratio test). This is done with an algorithm like RANSAC since the correspondences may include outliers.

But also you can speed up correspondences computation with a [kd-tree](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/kdtree.html).

So an alternative if you need a plain C implementation is relying on [Open SIFT](https://github.com/robwhess/opensift) by Rob Hess which includes everything you need, as well as a ready-to-use command-line tool (and thus example) of matching:

See [match.c](https://github.com/robwhess/opensift/blob/6233815/src/match.c).

---

```
typedef struct {
    int k1;
    int k2;
    double score;
} Pair;

Pair *
compare(
    Pair *pairs,
    const float *descr1,
    const float *descr2,
    int K1,
    int K2,
    int ND,
    float thresh
)
{
    int k1, k2;

    /* Loop over 1st image descr. */
    for (k1 = 0; k1 < K1; ++k1, descr1 += ND ) {
        float best = FLT_MAX;
        float second_best = FLT_MAX;
        int bestk = -1;

        /* Loop over 2nd image descr. and find the 1st and 2nd closest descr. */
        for (k2 = 0; k2 < K2; ++k2, descr2 += ND ) {
            int bin;
            float acc = 0;

            /* Compute the square L2 distance between descriptors */
            for (bin = 0 ; bin < ND ; ++bin) {
                float delta = descr1[bin] - descr2[bin];
                acc += delta*delta;
                if (acc >= second_best)
                    break;
            }

            if (acc < best) {
                second_best = best;
                best = acc;
                bestk = k2;
            }
            else if (acc < second_best) {
                second_best = acc;
            }
        }

        /* Rewind */
        descr2 -= ND*K2;

        /* Record the correspondence if the best descr. passes the ratio test */
        if (thresh * best < second_best && bestk != -1) {
            pairs->k1 = k1;
            pairs->k2 = bestk;
            pairs->score = best;
            pairs++;
        }
    }

    return pairs;
}
```

- `K1`: number of descriptors in image 1,
- `K2`: number of descriptors in image 2,
- `ND`: descriptor dimension (= 128 for SIFT),
- `descr1` and `descr2`: descriptors of image 1 and 2 resp. in row major order, e.g `K1` lines x `ND` columns),
- `thresh`: ratio test threshold value, e.g `1.5` in MATLAB code.

[1] see [7.1 Keypoint Matching](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf) from D. Lowe's paper.

Answer (score 0):

You will use the `vlfeat` library the same way you use any other library with C. First make sure you have the library installed on your computer and know where it is installed. You will need to include the required header for each part of `vlfeat` you are using. Generally a generic library header for `vlfeat` and then a specific header for `sift` (e.g. `#include "sift.h"`)(sometimes there is no general header). You will need to insure `gcc` or `g++` command includes the proper `INCLUDE_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` for your environment that will allow `gcc` to find your `vlfeat` files. (e.g. `-I/path/to/dir/holding_sift.h`  and `-L/path/to/vlfeatlib`) So you will end up with something like this for **C**:

```
gcc -o exename exename.c -I/path/to/dir/holding_sift.h -L/path/to/vlfeatlib -lvl
```

There is documentation on line that will help. See: [**how to setup a basic C++ project which uses the VLFeat library**](http://www.vlfeat.org/gcc.html) If you have further questions, just drop a line in the comments.

Comment: The C APIs are described at http://www.vlfeat.org/api/sift.html. There is only sift descriptor generating (extracting) API there. I cannot find a matching related API. And in the source, I find vl_ubcmatch.c which is doing a "basic matching algorithm". But I don't know how to call this algorithm function in this .c file (where there are many macros definitions which seem related to matlab). My major question is how to do SIFT matching algorithm if I use vlfeat?

Comment: That was the main part of the answer. You will include `sift.h` in your code along with the other includes (`stdio.h`, etc..). You will then use the function, with the correct arguments as specified in `sift.h` in your code. You will then compile the code (either `gcc` or `g++`) specifying the library `-lvl` so the linker knows to include that code, and you may/may not need to specify the `-I/path` and/or `-L/path` to have `gcc` and `ld` find the lib and `sift.h` header depending on your environment. No tricks.

Comment: You also need to insure you have the `binary` for the library installed, not just the source code. (you can build the binary vlfeat lib from source, but it is also provided in binary form)

Comment: I have two sift files extracted from two image files, 1.sift and 2.sift (or corresponding data structures in memory). How can I know if 2.sift matches 1.sift? Appreciate if any code snippet illustrated.

Comment: Ok, now we know where you are stuck. I haven't used sift before, but the sift files must contain some type of data struct that holds commonalities between image_1 and image_2 that will allow it to sew the two images together. What form that takes, I don't know. I would look at the data in the files and look for coordinates/color values/etc that sift has flagged as equivalent between the images. In order for vlfeat/sift to combine the images, those commonalities must be present. It may even contain an image map of filenames that contain equivalent data. If I get a chance tomorrow, I'll install